# What are the advantages and inconveniences of generalization or specialization of SQL tables?

Tags: database-design

This is a "theoretical" question linked to quality of table's definition.

I work on tires and, currently, I have a big table that, for each tire's label, contains a row with label's values. For more information go to this site: 
[DUNLOP Tire Label Explained](https://www.dunlop.eu/en_ae/consumer/learn/eu-tire-label-explained.html).

The used tire's labels are *Rolling Resistance* ('RR'), *Wet Grip* ('WG') and *Noise* ('NOISE').

Some columns in this big table are common to 'RR', 'WG' and 'NOISE' labels, but some other columns are specific to only one label. For example

```
CTC     LABEL GRADE G-SYMBOL G-VALUE AVERAGE
------  ----- ----- -------- ------- -------
345674  RR    B                      11,2
459864  WG    A                       2,1
893023  NOISE       ))       71      71,2
```

... where:

- `CTC` column is a term used to group all tires having same characteristics and belonging to same tire's line's name. Example: 'Goodyear EAGLE 155/60R20 95H Extra Load'.
- `LABEL` contains the *shortname* of the *label*.
- `CTC+LABEL` represents the table's primary key.
- `GRADE` contains the *grade* (*level*) of the *label*. For 'RR' and 'WG' the *grade* can vary from 'A' to 'G' where 'A' is the best *grade*. For 'NOISE', the *grade* is defined by a symbol and not a letter.
- `G-SYMBOL` has been added to represent the *grade* of 'NOISE'. Acceptable values are ')' or '))' or ')))', where ')' is the best value for 'NOISE'.
- `G-VALUE` has been added to represent the *grade* of 'NOISE'.
- `AVERAGE` is the *average* of all measures taken on some tires that are used to fix the *grade* of all tires belonging to same tire's *line's name*.

As you can see, `GRADE` is only used by 'RR' and 'WG' and `G-SYMBOL/G-VALUE` are only used by 'NOISE'. `AVERAGE` column are used by all *labels* but magnitude of value for each *label* are distinct. For 'RR', values are between '6' and '15' kg/T, and for 'NOISE' values are between '60' and '80' dB.

**Question(s)**:

How many tables must be defined to manage all these fields?

- **Solution A**: 1 big table?

  ```
  BIG-TABLE: CTC / LABEL / GRADE / G-SYMBOL / G-VALUE / AVERAGE
  ```
- **Solution B**: 3 tables (one in label)?

  ```
  RR:    CTC / AVERAGE / GRADE 
  WG:    CTC / AVERAGE / GRADE 
  NOISE: CTC / AVERAGE / G-SYMBOL / G-VALUE
  ```
- **Solution C**: 4 tables (one with specific field in label + 1 for common fields)?

  ```
  RR:     CTC / GRADE
  WG:     CTC / GRADE
  NOISE:  CTC / G-SYMBOL / G-VALUE
  COMMON: CTC / LABEL / AVERAGE
  ```
- **Solution X**: another solution?

What are the advantages and inconveniences of each solution?

**Some other considerations**:

- It is very uncommon to mix ALL labels.
- In the future, some new labels (as 'SNOW') will be added.

Comment: Hey Schlebe - you already have some solutions I see - have you tested them at all? Your question is very broad - I would suggest refining it down to a set of specific questions or you're unlikely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193394/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-have-several-mutually-exclusive-one-to-one-relationships/193401#193401

Comment: I have read the possible duplicate and vote up :-) But my questions is a little different. I'm waiting an answer that explains advantages and inconveniences of each solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Solution A is a bad solution if you have to add columns in future.
Using alter table in production environment is discouraged. Can hold the
database because of locks needed. This could not be a problem, but it really depend on the number of rows and concurrent transactions.
On the other hand is very simple to retrieve data, is a sort of denormalization,
so no join imply fast response time.

Solutions B and C are two similar desings. I dont like them. You wont be able to have cumulative 
data (count(1), group by..) in a single statement. You still have the problem above, if you need to
add columns. But now this problem is repeated 3 o 4 times, compared to solution A. Not good.

There is a 4th solution, using a table for key/value. In this scenario you have a big table whith
only the common columns, and a second table whith the following fields:

id / bigtable_id (references bigtable primary key) / key / value

Key column will store fields which apply only to certain type of tire coupled whith its value.
For example there could be rows like:

id ==> 1 /bigtable_id ==> whatever needed /key ==> grade   /value ==> A

id ==> 2 /bigtable_id ==> whatever needed /key ==> g-value /value ==> 71

There is an one-to-many relationship between tables.
This is the solution I have seen most of the time. Is simple to manage, no need to alter table:
if you need a new field just add new record/records.

In my opinion the fact that mix label is uncommon, is a secondary issue in design. If the problem
is the number of rows, you can use partitions and subpartitions, but I prefer have the DB desing in 
order. Of course this is only *my way* to see order   ;)

my 2 cent

Comment: I vote up for the effort to write an answer but I dislike solution 4 that is similar to PARAMETER table that we use where I work. This solution contains metadata in each rows and is always implemented using String type for any values. The management of new fields is perhaps simple, but I suppose that the selection of rows is complex because we need to define an LEFT JOIN for any fields in row ! But it is interesting.